# Misuse-resistant authenticated encryption based on SHA-3/Blake2b and AES-CTR/ChaCha20

Tags: hash, cryptanalysis, symmetric, stream-cipher, blake2

I am wondering if the following is a useful misuse-resistant authenticated encryption scheme:

#### Parameters (shared by many users):

- Choose a hash function $H$, such as Blake2 or Keccak.  SHA2 could also be used.
- Choose a stream cipher $E$, such as ChaCha20 and AES in CTR mode.

#### Inputs

- Up to a large amount of associated data $A$.
- Up to $2^{64}$ bytes of plaintext $m$.
- Secret key $K$, which must have at least $k$ bits of entropy but can be much longer.

#### Outputs

- Ciphertext $C$, of the same length as the plaintext.
- An auth tag $t$, of 256 or 512 bits depending on the choice of $H$.

Decryption takes $A$, $C$, $t$, and $K$ as inputs and returns either $m$ or the symbol $\text{FAIL}$ if the message was forged.

All lengths are 64 bit, little-endian encoded.

Encryption algorithm:

1. Calculate the auth tag $t$ as $H(len(K)||K||len(A)||A||len(P)||P)$.
2. Calculate the shared secret $S$ as $H(len(K)||K||t)$.
3. Use $S$ as the key for stream cipher encryption. Any extra bits can be use for the nonce.  Bits beyond that are discarded.

Decryption algorithm:

1. Calculate shared secret (same as step 2 of encryption).
2. Perform stream cipher decryption (same as encryption step, since encryption = decryption for a stream cipher).
3. Recompute auth tag $t'$ from plaintext, AAD and key (same as encryption step 1).
4. The message is rejected unless $t=t'$.

#### Claim

- 256-bit confidentiality.
- 256-bit integrity when used with a 256-bit hash.
- 512-bit integrity when used with a 512-bit hash and $K$ has at least 512 bits of entropy.
- IND-CCA2 security provided that the AAD is never repeated with the same key.
- If the AAD repeats the only leak is whether a message repeated.

I would definitely like to know if this cryptosystem lives up to my claims.  I doubt it, since I am not a cryptographer -- but I would be glad if I was proven wrong.

Comment: if you are not using the AAD it is not nonce misuse resistant. Also you used the same symbol for AAD and the tag, tag should be lowercase t

Comment: The encryption key is derived from the auth tag, which is derived from the ciphertext C.  Where does C come from?

Comment: @TimMcLean typo, fixed

Comment: What [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) are your $len$s? ​ ​

Comment: Little-endian byte order

Comment: Are the length fields fixed-length?  Also, what is $k$?

Comment: @TimMcLean The length fields are 64 bits, little-endian encoded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 256-bit confidentiality

Let's assume that we're using AES256-CTR and a 256-bit hash.  A new 256-bit key $S$ is derived for each message.  Since AES256 requires a 256-bit key, there are no extra bits in $S$ available for use in the nonce, suggesting that a constant nonce is used.  I believe this is vulnerable to a multi-target attack.

The first block of ciphertext $C_0 = \text{AES256}(S, 0^{128}) \oplus P_0$, where $P_0$ is the first block of plaintext.  Suppose that this block is predictable to the attacker (think of SMTP for example: it's not unusual for the first 16 bytes to be predictable) or attacker-controlled.  The attacker can compute $K_0 = C_0 \oplus P_0 = \text{AES256}(S, 0^{128})$ to get the direct output of the block cipher.

Suppose that the attacker can observe (and maybe encourage the sending of) lots of encrypted messages.  The attacker can compute $\text{AES256}(x, 0^{128})$ for many values of $x$, and check to see if any of those values match any of the $K_0$s the attacker observed.  With $2^{20}$ messages (and therefore $2^{20}$ $K_0$s), the attacker should find an $x$ that works after about $2^{256-20} = 2^{236}$ tries, allowing the attacker to decrypt a single message.  I believe this violates the claim of 256-bit confidentiality.

A similar attack can be applied to ChaCha20 when it is used with a constant nonce.  In the case of a 512-bit hash, this seems to leave enough bits of $S$ for a complete nonce, which should mitigate this attack.

> The message is rejected unless $t=t'$.

This is an implementation issue, but this is vulnerable to timing attacks unless a constant-time comparison is used.

Comment: Does this work for a 512-bit hash or for ChaCha20?

Comment: @Demetri see edit.

Answer (score 2):

Your scheme can't make due with much less than the family $\: m \mapsto H(\hspace{.03 in}\operatorname{len}(K\hspace{.02 in})||\hspace{.02 in}K\hspace{.02 in}||\hspace{.02 in}m)$

serving as a [PRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_function_family) when no message is a prefix of any other message.

(Such pseudorandomness does not follow from full

[collision-resistance and second-preimage resistance and onewayness].)

Comment: This doesn't work because the length fields are fixed-length.

Comment: @ everyone else : ​ Note that my original answer did work when I posted it. ​ ​ ​ ​